# IE6 - Element jumps when loading

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

In IE6 one element (an iframe in a table, to be precise) on my page for a short time appears at an absolutely wrong position, and then, when loading is done, jumps into the correct position. There are many bugs documented on the internet, but I couldn't find any information about how to fix this. The page can be viewed here:
http://www.findix.com/haueser-kaufen/exklusiver-reiterhof-mit-charme--in-neuenburg_a206886.htm
PS: If the link doesn't work for you, try copy&pasting it.. Weird.

Comment: Are you refering to the Google Ads iFrames?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

You have multiple calls to

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Try putting just a single call to this script just before your closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: The location of these calls are the locations of the Google adds on the page visually, can't really place them anywhere.